# Getting table name in joined mysql query result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
SELECT
*
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.id=table2.ref
```

How to distinctly identify column which are from table1 or table2. Is there anyway to get table name in alias which can be used to identify column by table name?If it matters i am using PHP to fetch from database.

Comment: I am curious, why do you need that? in my 15+ year experience I've never had such an issue.

Comment: I am fetching from different table using joined query. each table represents a class in php. some class has properties which are object of other class. I dont want to populate each of properties manually. if it is possible to get table name with the columns i would dynamically populate object and assign to base class properties.

Comment: AFIK you have to set an alias name for each column you request

Answer (score 0):

Well, your reason is fair but the implementation is unusual.

When each table represents a class in php, it is called **ORM** - Object-relational mapping.
And when it is used, an object already knows it's fields, because each table being only a reflection of the class properties. Frankly, with ORM nobody is going to create tables manually - they are created (or altered) based on the object properties.
So, an object always can tell it's fields from others.

As for your literal question - no, there is no way to get such info, as far as I know